# php activerecord problem : 'ActiveRecord\RecordNotFound' with message 'Couldn't find Setting without an ID'

Tags: php, static-variables, phpactiverecord

i am using php activerecord in my own mvc framework.

i extends AppModel from \ActiveRecord\Model

```
class AppModel extends \ActiveRecord\Model
{

}
```

and other models extends from AppModel

```
class Setting extends AppModel
{
    static $table_name = 'setting';     
}
```

get an error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\RecordNotFound' with
>   message 'Couldn't find Setting without an ID'

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Might help if you could post your `setting` table and any code you're using to try and fetch rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the leading slash from your class declaration?

```
class AppModel extends ActiveRecord\Model {

}
```